# RowExpander for duplicate records in Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a grid in Extjs and I want to add rowExpander on a condition, The condition is:

If there is more than one record with same ID in store, then only one record will be visible in grid, but a rowExpander(plus icon) will be added with the record, And when we click on plus icon it will show all the remaining records of ID.

I want a grid like this:

---

|     | ID | NAME | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | FIELD4 | FIELD5 |

---

|  +  | 01 | ABCD | TEST01 | TEST02 | TEST03 | TEST04 | TEST05 |

---

|     | 02 | ABCD | TEST01 | TEST02 | TEST03 | TEST04 | TEST05 |

---

|     | 03 | ABCD | TEST01 | TEST02 | TEST03 | TEST04 | TEST05 |

---

|     | 04 | ABCD | TEST01 | TEST02 | TEST03 | TEST04 | TEST05 |

|     | 04 | ABCD | TEST01 | TEST02 | TEST03 | TEST04 | TEST05 |

|  -  | 04 | ABCD | TEST01 | TEST02 | TEST03 | TEST04 | TEST05 |

|     | 04 | ABCD | TEST01 | TEST02 | TEST03 | TEST04 | TEST05 |

|     | 04 | ABCD | TEST01 | TEST02 | TEST03 | TEST04 | TEST05 |

---

Please suggest a solution for this.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want just show those rows, or edit them too?

Comment: I want to edit them too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some research about this problem this year.

As I understand the framework, it's impossible to have a nested grid in `grid` component. Using some hacks, you can only create a read-only subgrid inside `rowExpander` plugin. (actually, you can create components inside, but you won't catch any events from them)

In your case you can try to use `grouping` feature to group records in your store.

I've also seen another implementation — show window with a subgrid after click on main grid row.

Hope this information will help you.